# INSERT 3 flag in a mapping in relation to a field in a table

Tags: database, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

i have this scenario in power center designer:

I have a first table `COSTO_PDR` with primary key:

```
ID_PDR and YEARS
```

I have a second table `GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR` with primary key:

```
ID_PDR,YEARS and ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO.
```

`ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO` has only one of this 3 values: `A,B and C.`

I want on my target `TARGET_COSTO_PDR`:
this field:  `ID_PDR   YEARS   A   B   C`

where `A, B and C` are boolean field relating to the values of `ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO` of `GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR`..

I do a LOOKUP TRASFORMATION for to take `ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO` but i have only a value.

for example:

```
COSTO_PDR
---------------
ID_PDR | YEARS|
---------------
1111111  2014

GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR
---------------------------------------
ID_PDR  |  YEARS  |ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO|
---------------------------------------
1111111  2014       A
1111111  2014       B
1111111  2014       C

TARGET_COSTO_PDR
------------------------------------
ID_PDR |  YEARS  |  A  |  B  |  C  |
------------------------------------
1111111  2014      Y      Y    Y
```

How i can do for to have this target in POWERCENTER DESIGNER????
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Create an unconnected lookup on **GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR** with the conditions on all the three fields

```
ID_PDR = inp_ID_PDR
YEARS = inp_YEARS
ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO = inp_ID_TIPOLOGIA_PREMIO
```

Return any one of the fields from the lookup

Now in an expression transformation create 3 output ports corresponding to your 3 target fields A, B and C with the following expressions:

**out_A**: `IIF(ISNULL(LKP.lkp_GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR(src_ID_PDR, src_YEARS, 'A')),'N','Y')`

**out_B**: `IIF(ISNULL(LKP.lkp_GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR(src_ID_PDR, src_YEARS, 'B')),'N','Y')`

**out_C**: `IIF(ISNULL(LKP.lkp_GAS_COSTO_PDR_PREMI_STOR(src_ID_PDR, src_YEARS, 'C')),'N','Y')`